# Adding background to days with event with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I've defined a function to check whether a date has an event that returns true or false. For some reason, it's turning the cell of the next day to the color instead of the day that has an event. Oddly enough, my partner is using linux and it displays correctly for him, but every computer or vm i try it on with any operating system displays incorrectly. Here is the relevant code and a jsfiddle that displays the problem:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var events = [];
$.ajax({
                url : 'https://showmeyouraxels.me/browse.php',
                type : 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(e){
                    console.log(e[0].title);
                    for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
                            events.push({
                                    title : e[i].title,
                                    start : moment(e[i].start).toDate('2017/07/18 12h:00'),
                                    end : moment(e[i].end).toDate('2017/07/18 12h:30'),
                                    icon: "https://www.qrstuff.com/images/sample.png",
                            });
                        }
                    console.log(events);
                    createCalendar();
                }
        });
function createCalendar(){

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        customButtons: {
            myCustomButton: {
                text: 'Add Event',
                click: function() {
                  alert('add event');
                }
            }
        },
         header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        editable : false,
        eventLimit: true,
                eventLimitText: '',
                dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                    if ( !dateHasEvent(date) ){
                            cell.css("background-color", "initial");
                            console.log('no event ' + date.toDate());
                    }
                    else if ( dateHasEvent(date) ){
                            cell.css("background-color", "#6b7c8c");
                            console.log('event ' + date.toDate());
                    }
                },

        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view, element) {
                    var inner = new Date(calEvent.start) + ' to ' + new Date(calEvent.end);
                    swal({
                            title: calEvent.title,
                            html: true,
                            text: inner,
                            allowOutsideClick: true
                    });
        },
                dayClick: function(dayEvent, jsEvent, view, element){
                    console.log(dayEvent);
                },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.find('.fc-content').html('<img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/flag.svg" height="10px"/><br>' +event.title);

        },
    });
        calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);
    }

    function dateHasEvent(date) {
        var hasEvent = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
         var thatDate = events[i].start.toString();
         thatDate = thatDate.split(' ');
         thatDate = thatDate[1] +' '+thatDate[2] +' '+thatDate[3];

         var thisDate = date.toDate().toString();
         thisDate = thisDate.split(' ');
         thisDate = thisDate[1] +' '+thisDate[2] +' '+thisDate[3];

         if(thisDate == thatDate){
             hasEvent = true;
            }
        }
        return hasEvent;
    }

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/883/)

I've been scratching my head for the past day and i'd have to imagine it's something stupid that i'm missing. 
Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: the fiddle doesn't work, so difficult to reproduce the issue. Your server doesn't allow CORS requests, so JSFiddle can't fetch the events. Can you make an example using some static event data which still shows the problem?

Comment: P.S. Why is your dateHasEvent function doing all that mucking about with string manipulation of dates when you could just use momentJS to compare them in one line? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/. It's not impossible that your problem lies in all that convoluted logic somewhere